# Can Google Remote Desktop Browser Addon be stable in Linux?

Tags: chrome, remote-desktop

One beta of Remote Desktop is from 2014 [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8PMxG69VJ6o). 
Otherwise, it has been silent. 
I activated the addon in my Chromebook but the sync does not start in Linux so I am thinking if it makes any sense to use such a plugin in Linux. 
Normally, I use SSH to get an access to my PCs, but now, I want to test this addon.

OS: Debian 8.7
Internet browser: Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Connection: access your Linux PC from Chromebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No supports exist for such a feature in connecting Linux PC Desktop frontend to Chromebook. I think my source was confused.